# Permission denied Error when running Cucumber feature file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, aptana3

I'm getting the following error when running a single feature file using Aptana studio 3:

```
$ cucumber features/ShopAndBrowse/MCOM/SearchMCOM.feature URL=http://www1.preprod7macys.fds.com/ SITE=MCOM ENV=13B DB2=YES
Using the default profile...
DB2 DATABASE CONNECTION ESTABLISHED - MLQ10
Feature: Search Feature

  ←[36m@high_MCOM←[0m ←[36m@regression_MCOM←[0m
  Scenario: verify that user should be able to search and compare  for Items in domestic mode←[90m # features\ShopAndBrowse\MCOM\SearchMCOM.feature
:5←[0m
←[31m Permission denied - C:\ProgramData/ruby-uuid (Errno::EACCES)←[0m
←[31m org/jruby/RubyFile.java:315:in `initialize'←[0m
←[31m org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1176:in `open'←[0m
←[31m c:/jruby-1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/uuid-2.3.7/lib/uuid.rb:364:in `open_lock'←[0m
```

- Using Windows 7 64 bit os
- Using Aptana Studio 3
- Already running as 'Run as administrator'
- Using 'jruby-1.7.0'

Comment: This file path looks wrong: `C:\ProgramData/ruby-uuid`. It's mixing back and forward slashes. I'm not familiar with Aptana, but is that path configurable anywhere?

Comment: @ Jonathan - I checked in Aptana Tool/ Ruby files but couldn't find any place to configure that file